# Shapeless: Iterate over the types in a Coproduct

Tags: scala, shapeless, coproduct

I want to do something really simple, but I'm struggling to craft the correct search or just understanding some of the solutions I've seen.

Given a method that takes a generic type parameter which is a Coproduct;

```
def apply[T <: Coproduct] = {
  ...
}
```

How can I iterate over the types that form the coproduct?  Specifically, for each type that is a case class, I'd like to recursively examine each field and build up a map with all the information.

Currently I'm working around this using a builder pattern, which I'll post here in case it's useful to others;

```
class ThingMaker[Entities <: Coproduct] private {
  def doThings(item: Entities): Set[Fact] = {
    ...
  }

def register[A <: Product with Serializable]: ThingMaker[A :+: Entities] = {
    // useful work can be done here on a per type basis
    new ThingMaker[A :+: Entities]
  }
}

object ThingMaker {
  def register[A <: Product with Serializable]: ThingMaker[A :+: CNil] = {
    // useful work can be done here on a per type basis
    new ThingMaker[A :+: CNil]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to inspect values, you can simply pattern match on a coproduct like on any other value...

```
def apply[T <: Coproduct](co: T): Any = co match {
  case Inl(MyCaseClass(a, b, c)) => ???
  ...
}
```

...but if you want to be more precise than that, for instance to have a return type that depends on the input, or to inspect the types inside this coproduct to summon implicits, then you can write *the exact same pattern matching expression* using a type class and several implicit definition:

```
trait MyFunction[T <: Coproduct] {
  type Out
  def apply(co: T): Out
}

object MyFunction {
  // case Inl(MyCaseClass(a, b, c)) =>
  implicit val case1 = new MyFunction[Inl[MyCaseClass]] {
    type Out = Nothing
    def apply(co: Inl[MyCaseClass]): Out = ???
  }

  // ...
}
```

In general, when you want *iterate* over all types of a coproduct, you will always follow the same tail recursive structure. As a function:

```
def iterate[T <: Coproduct](co: T): Any = co match {
  case Inr(head: Any)       => println(v)
  case Inl(tail: Coproduct) => iterate(tail)
  case CNil                 => ???
}
```

Or as a "dependently typed function":

```
trait Iterate[T <: Coproduct]
object Iterate {
  implicit def caseCNil = new Iterate[CNil] {...}
  implicit def caseCCons[H, T <: Coproduct](implicit rec: Iterate[T]) =
    new Iterate[H :+: T] {...}
}
```

You can for instance ontain the name of each type in a coproduct using an addition `ClassTag` implicit:

```
trait Iterate[T <: Coproduct] { def types: List[String] }

object Iterate {
  implicit def caseCNil = new Iterate[CNil] {
    def types: List[String] = Nil
  }

  implicit def caseCCons[H, T <: Coproduct]
    (implicit
      rec: Iterate[T],
      ct: reflect.ClassTag[H]
    ) =
      new Iterate[H :+: T] {
        def types: List[String] = ct.runtimeClass.getName :: rec.types
      }
}

implicitly[Iterate[Int :+: String :+: CNil]].types // List(int, java.lang.String)
```

Because of the way Scala lets you influence implicit priority, it's actually possible to translate any recursive function with pattern matching into this "dependently typed function" pattern. This is unlike Haskell where such function can only be written if call cases of the match expression are provably non-overlapping.

Comment: Thanks for your really thorough answer.  The reason pattern matching doesn't work for me, is this is a library and I don't know the concrete types that users will call it with.  Is there way to generically iterate over all the types without knowing them?  I essentially just want to do some reflection on them, build a list of fields, that sort of thing.

Comment: Your iterate function is almost what I need - except I need to do the work of inspecting the types, prior to having an instance of the type.  The idea being that users of this API will create it with some Coproduct, e.g. Person :+: Address :+: CNil - at this point we'll inspect the types Person and Address and build the metadata needed (expensive).  Later on, calls to this API will supply an actual instance of a Person etc and the metadata is used to do the real work of the API.  Does this make sense?

Comment: Makes sense, just update the Interate dependently typed function to take an addition `implicit m: Metadata[H]` parameter, and but whatever you want in there.

Comment: Thanks - I don't see a Metadata type anywhere, is this part of Shapeless?

Comment: It's not. The idea is to use a custom `trait Metadata[T]` to do whatever "build the metadata needed (expensive)" means, for instance using a `TypeTag`.

Comment: If you have a chance and could update your answer to show a working example that uses this technique to do something trivial like just get the full name of each type in the Coproduct then I'll happily accept your solution.